# printf changes my output

Tags: c, arrays, loops, printf, variable-length-array

[I'm trying to solve this challenge](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/lisa-workbook) on Hackerrank.

I've reached a problem where I cannot proceed, but I can't see where I've gone wrong - and I'm hoping someone here can help.

My current solution is as follows:

```
int main() {

    int n,k,p,count,total; 
    int t[n];
    scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&t[i]);
    }
    p = 1;
    total=0;
    for(int x = 0; x < n; x++){
        for(int j = 1; j <= t[x]; j++, count++){
            if(count>k){
                count = 1;
                p++;
            }
            if(j==p){
                total++;
            }
            //printf("j: %d p: %d\tcount: %d\n",j,p,count);
        }
        p++;
        count=1;
    }
    printf("%d",total);

    return 0;
}
```

The printf that I have commented out is what changes my eventual output.
For example, with an input of:

> 10 5
>
> 3 8 15 11 14 1 9 2 24 31

I should be getting an answer of 8. If I un-comment that `printf()` function, then I can see the current problem number and page number to see if it's 'special'.
If I leave it un-commented, my eventual output is 8, which is what I want. But I don't want all the iterations printed out as well.
The problem I have is that when I remove that line, or comment it out, the output becomes 5, not 8.
What is causing this to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, while defining `int t[n];`, you're using `n` uninitialized. That , invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To elaborate, `n` is an automatic local variable that is not initialized explicitly, so the content of that variable is indeterminate. Attempt to use an indeterminate value leads to UB.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. [...]

and, annex §J.2, undefined behavior,

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate

You need to move the definition of `int t[n];` **after** you have successfully scanned the value from the user. Check the return value of `scanf()` to ensure the success.

Answer (score 0):

array must be of fixed size
 you can create after reading number of elements n using
 calloc(),malloc()